# Hide Divs by Data Attribute and Make Togglers Work (Hide/Show)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this code for my view layout. I need to hide all divs except for root ones in js and get the toggler buttons work onclick to hide childs of an element and to show them. I'm not really sure how to do that. I'm pretty new to JS. Thanks.

```
    @model List<Tree_List.Controllers.Element>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

@helper PopulateDivs(List<Tree_List.Controllers.Element> elements)
        {
foreach (var element in elements)
{
        <div class="toggler_wrapper">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-"/ data-id="@element.ID" data-parent="@element.PARNET_ID">
        </div>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="@element.ID" data-parent="@element.PARNET_ID">
            @element.NAME
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
            @if (element.CHILDS.Count() > 0)
            {
                @PopulateDivs(element.CHILDS);
            }
        </div>
}
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function init() {

    });
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
    @PopulateDivs(Model)
</div>
```

Comment: You would most likely get more answers if you posted the HTML output instead of the C# View code

Comment: Right click your output page. go to view page source. Post the generated html code here. That would give us a better insight of what yu want to accomplish

Comment: What do you mean by everything apart from the root `div`?  The root div is 'wrapper', so you mean you want to hide and show `element_wrapper`?

Comment: @Luke Yes, I want to hide all element_wrapper elements except for the first ones

Comment: First of all you probably want another `DIV` layer around pairs of `DIV`s with class `toggler_wrapper` and `element_wrapper`. This additional `DIV` should sensibly have `data-id=@element.ID`. So, broad strokes from there: you iterate over the list selected by `#@element.ID` add a click listener to `#@element.ID input.toggler_btn` which contains the logic to toggle visibility of `#@element.ID div.element_wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.toggler_btn', function() {

    // Hide all element_wrapper elements
    $('div.element_wrapper').hide();

    // Show the nearest one - this is the 'except the first one' bit
    $(this).parent('.toggler_wrapper').next('div.element_wrapper').show();
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2f4zoxb/)